# Magento 2 : Open calendar on text click

Tags: magento2

I have made an input box and on clicking input box the calendar appears and we can select the date and value is stored. Now i want the same functionality instead of input box, i want text. On clicking text the calendar appears and the same functionality should happen. Can anyone suggest anything.

```
<div class="product-ddate-calendar-block">
    <input type="text" style="width: auto" 
        class="input-text example-date_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getProduct()->getId() ?>" 
        name="example-date_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getProduct()->getId() ?>"
        aria-required="true"/> 
    <input type="hidden"

        class="input-text example-date-itemId_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>" 
        name="example-date-itemId_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"
        value = "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"
        />
    <input type="hidden"
        class="input-text example-date-optionId_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $optionId ?>" 
        name="example-date-optionId_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $optionId ?>"
         value = "option_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $optionId ?>"
        />
</div>
```

Comment: But how do you post the selected date if you not using input box? Either you need to use text box or one hidden field otherwise you cannot post the selected date.

Comment: Okay how can i do this with input field hidden

Comment: Do you want it for frontend form? If yes then can you please update your code to the question what you have done yet?

Comment: Yes for the frontend form. I have added the code for my calendar field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add calender on text click by following steps:

**Step 1:**
Add the html for the text like below:

```
<div class="calender_wrap">
    <span id="text_calender">Select Date</span>
</div>
```

**Step 2:**
Add the css code like below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .calender_wrap .ui-datepicker{display: none !important; position: absolute;}
    .calender_wrap .ui-datepicker.showCalender{display: block !important;}
</style>
```

**Step 3:**
Add the javascript code like below:

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/calendar"
    ], function($){
        $(".calender_wrap").calendar({
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                $(".calender_wrap .ui-datepicker").removeClass('showCalender');
                alert(dateText);
            }
        });
        $("#text_calender").on('click', function(){
            $('.calender_wrap .ui-datepicker').toggleClass('showCalender');
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function(e){
            var container = $(".calender_wrap");
            if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
            {
                $(".calender_wrap .ui-datepicker").removeClass('showCalender');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Flush the cache and test.

Comment: Thankyou for sharing code .But i am not able to select any value.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How can we get the value of selected date in form. I have a form in which the value is passed to a controller.

Comment: You can create a hidden field and put the selected value to that field onSelect event. You are currently getting the selected value at onSelect event.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome! Happy Coding!